# Как получить [Общительный] и [Искренний] на мете?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, знаки, чат, мета

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

1. > Опубликовал в чате 10 сообщений, получивших хотя бы по одной звезде
2. > Опубликовать в чате 10 сообщений, которые были отмечены звездой 10 разными участниками

О каком чате речь?

Comment: Первый раз прочитал и подумал на основном, думаю какие же сложности, а потом глянул - Мета...., интересный вопрос...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Проблема в том, что список знаков для всех сайтов одинаков и в некоторых случаях содержит знаки, которые невозможно получить в принципе.

На англомете SO тоже знаков таких [ни у кого нет](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/65/talkative). Есть [похожий вопрос](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276729/3240681) на MSO про знаки чата на мета сайте, закрытый дубликатом на вопрос об общем списке знаков.

Comment: Почему же не поправят?

Comment: @VerNick не хотят отдельно каждый сайт настраивать.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i < StackExchange.Length(); i++) { StackExchange[i].badges.Talkative.change(); }